# Model factory access Faker inside state function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Using Laravel Eloquent factory to generate faker data which's great for most of the logic. How can I need to pass data to the state function but still use faker?

E.g select a salary for the 'contract' which's between the min/max salary set for the 'position'.

```
$positions = Position::factory()
    ->state(function() use($team) {
        return ['team_id' => $team->id];
    })
    ->count(5)
    ->create();

foreach($positions as $position) {
    $contract = Contract::factory()
        ->for($position)
        ->state(function () use ($position) {
            return [
                'salary' => $this->faker->randomFloat(2, $position->salary_min, $position->salary_max),
            ];
        })
        ->count(1)
        ->create();
}
```

This code throws error Cannot access protected property faker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel factory faker is just an instance of Generator class, you can get your instance using service container:

```
use Faker\Generator;
foreach($positions as $position) {
    $faker = resolve(Generator::class);
    $contract = Contract::factory()
        ->for($position)
        ->state(function () use ($position) {
            return [
                'salary' =>$faker->randomFloat(2, $position->salary_min, $position->salary_max),
            ];
        })
        ->count(1)
        ->create();
}
```